# Back button in ie browser

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http-headers

Whenever I press back button of IE, Browser Display message "Web page expired".

I have one registration page that is reg.php now i have save data in save_reg.php and than back button press and message display " Web page expired".

I have try following code:

```
header("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
session_cache_limiter("must-revalidate");
```

But message stay remain

Comment: you are adding an expiration date in the past and expect that the page won't be expired?

Comment: i have one registration page that is reg.php now i have save data in save_reg.php and than back button press and message display " Expired"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the page you are going back to was a POST request. It has absolutely nothing to do with the headers.

The easiest way to get rid of this is with the following code at the beginning:

```
session_start();
if( $_POST) {
  $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_POST;
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit;
}
if( $_SESSION['postdata']) {
  $_POST = $_SESSION['postdata'];
  unset($_SESSION['postdata']);
}
```

Comment: Didn't notice that you were explicitly setting the page to expire 13 years ago. Still, this can be useful for POST requests since they don't get cached.

Answer (score 0):

Set expiration date in future:

```
header("Expires: ".date("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $desiredDuration)." GMT");
```

[`time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch and add to it desired time in seconds and format it with [`date`](http://php.net/date) function.

Comment: @downvoter Could you explain why you have downvoted, please? IMO, this is neither wrong, nor misleading answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using

```
BrowserMatch MSIE force-no-vary
```

in my .htaccess file. The Vary header is generated by mod_rewrite and ie doesn't handle it well.